# Adding new system call to utility.c in Minix

Tags: c, system-calls, minix

I am trying to implement a system call in Minix and I'm having trouble understanding where I need to go. This is the system call I need to add which returns 0 on success and -1 on failure while also returning `a+b`, `a-b`, and `a*b`:

```c
int mycall(int a, int b, int *sum, int *difr, int *prod);
```

What I've done:

- main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, d, p, r, s;
    a = 3;
    b = 2;
    int mycall(int a, int b, int *s, int *d, int *p);
    r = mycall(a, b, &s, &d, &p);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d,%d,%d,%d\n", r, s, d, p);
    return 0;
}
```

- added mycall.c to same directory (given code has typos, I assume that `k` should be `r`):

```c
#include <lib.h>
int mycall(int a, int b, int *sum, int *difr, int *prod)
{
    message m;
    int r;

    m.m1_i1 = a;
    m.m1_i2 = b;

    k = _syscall(MM, 58, &m);
    if(r < 0) return -1;
    *sum = m.m1_i1;
    *difr = m.m1_i2;
    *prod = m.m1_i3;
    return k;
}
```

- added to /usr/mm/proto.h:

```c
    _PROTOTYPE( int do_mycall, (void));
```

- added `do_mycall    /* 58 = unused */` to /usr/mm/table.c

All that needs to be done is to implement the call in /usr/mm/utility.c. This is what I have so far:

```c
PUBLIC int do_mycall()
{
    int a, b;
    a = mm_in.m1_i1;
    b = mm_in.m1_i2;

    /* my guess */
    mm_in.m1_i1 = a+b;
    mm_in.m1_i2 = a-b;
    mm_in.m1_i3 = a*b;

    /* mp_reply is in mproc struct of this process */

    return OK;
}
```

The current code when ran (after rebuilding the kernel) gives `-1,0,0,0` which is wrong, but I am not sure how to proceed. When opening `mproc.h`, I can see `message mp_reply;` but I don't know how this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong here, but I suggest you read their syscall page thoroughly and see an implementation of it.

Comment: Just to see where the code goes wrong, I threw in a `printf()` in utility.c function and got nothing, so I'm thinking the call never gets there which would explain why I'm not getting the correct results though I'm not sure where the error occurs.

Comment: I wonder if `printf()` like functions will work inside a syscall. Maybe it does, given its a MT kernel. Please do post your reply here. Minix is awfully under represented.

Comment: According to this [exercise](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/nick.cook/csc2025/minix/syscall-exercise1.html), they show they can use `printf()` so I assume I can though I'm not sure which version Minix they're using (I'm using 2), or if that would cause a difference. And Minix is way under represented. It's so hard to find any help. I'll probably end up talking to my professor, and once I get it working, post an answer here just in case anyone else finds themselves in my position.

Comment: After almost an hour of searching I finally found the mproc struct file (no clue it was in `/usr/src/mm/mproc.h`), I know to use `mproc->mp_reply.m1_i1` (for example) but even after assigning values I still get the same output. I think my problem is that the function never gets called though I'm not sure where the link needs to be made...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working thanks to a classmate. proto.h and table.c files are correct. Had to change all `k`'s to `r`'s in mycall.c. The big change was in utility.c and how I rebuilt the image.

`utility.c` code:

```c
PUBLIC int do_mycall()
{
    int a, b;
    a = mm_in.m1_i1;
    b = mm_in.m1_i2;

    mproc[mm_in.m_source].mp_reply.m1_i1 = a+b;
    mproc[mm_in.m_source].mp_reply.m1_i2 = a-b;
    mproc[mm_in.m_source].mp_reply.m1_i3 = a*b;

    return OK;

}
```

Rebuilding the image (in Minix):

```
> make hdboot        (KEEP NOTE OF VERSION NUMBER AT END OF SCRIPT!)
> shutdown
```

In Minix boot monitor (QEMU):

```
d0p0>set
# change image to /minix/(YOUR VERSION)
# change net on image to ...;image=/minix/(YOUR VERSION NUMBER)
# save
d0p0>boot
```